# Concatenate each two files with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, merge

I have several files like this

```
BR1.txt
NH1.csv
BR2.txt
NH2.csv
BR3.txt
NH3.csv
```

and I want to concatenate each `BR` with `NH` in one file.

Comment: We will be glad to help, but you need to be clearer. You mean you want three resulting files, `cat BRx.txt NHx.csv`, with `x` from 1 to 3?

Comment: excatly so i will get file 1 = NH1+BH1 ; file2 =NH2+BH2 ...................to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
for br in BR*.txt; do
    num="${br#BR}"
    num="${num%.*}"
    nh="NH${num}.csv"
    cat "$br" "$nh" > "out${num}.txt"
done
```

but without sample input/output it's a guess.

Comment: this is exactly what i need sir thank you so so so much ! ^^

Answer (score 1):

```bash
set -- BR*.txt
count=0

for name in NH*.csv; do
        count=$(( count + 1 ))
        cat "$1" "$name" >"file$count"
        shift
done
```

This first sets the list of positional parameters to the `BR` files and then iterates over the `NH` files.  For each `NH` filename in `$name`, it concatenates the next `BR` file with it and writes the result to a file called `file` followed by some number.  By using `shift`, it makes `$1` be the next `BR` file for the following iteration.

This effectively pairs up each `BR` file with its corresponding `NH` file, assuming the two sets of files are equal in number and follow the same numbering system (so that the sort in the correct way).